# I am unable to push https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/PCF-demo file

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pcf, pivotal-web-services

This is my first application which I am trying to push into Pivotal cloud foundry.it fails when right at the end.The Status in the PWS is Crashed.

https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/PCF-demo

sample logs are as below:

```
d97aea708a payload: {"instance"=>"d2108b14-9252-4db6-69c6-1aff", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "
exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>15210
84086634418047, "version"=>"26617120-9c7a-49be-bb8d-404313ee655e"}
   2018-03-14T22:21:27.24-0500 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-deploy the application and besides the error message you mentioned I also got:

```
2018-03-19T21:27:33.35+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Cannot calculate JVM memory configuration: There is insufficient memory remaining for heap. Memory limit 512M is less than allocated memory 603988K (-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=91988K, -Xss1M * 250 threads)
```

It seems the application you are trying to deploy cannot allocate enough memory. That's because in the `manifest.yml` [the memory limit is set to `512M`](https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/PCF-demo/blob/d7b6114be7b45f9a1462d81168eef68b95e09066/manifest.yml#L4), but according to the error message above, the application needs more than that to start. You can find more about memory limits in the context of CF applications [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#memory).

You can solve the issue by increasing the amount of memory in the `manifest.yml`, or by overwriting the memory limit in the command line:

```
$ cf push -m 1G
```

By doing that I was able to successfully deploy and start the application.